# Dynamic date format in text output step in PDI

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I am using PDI to run sql queries stored in an oracle DB and then extracting the results to a file using a text file output step. Every extract is different so I can't set the output fields. How can I default the date format of the output to whatever is specified for that particular extract?

I have a lookup table with the SQL query and the date format I want for that query.

I realise I could use formatting on the query itself, but I would like to know if it can be done in PDI instead. There are literally hundreds of these so it would mean far less work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no-standard way, I know to do this. Except of course to use a `User Defined Java Class` or a `Metadata Injector`.

However, the data format is irrelevant in PDI up to when you want to write them on a file. And even if you have hundreds of possible on the input (which does not bother Kettle at all), I am sure you have relatively few of them on the output.

So, just before the last output step, have a lookup in your table, and switch to the approriate `Select value` step, in which the `Metadata tag` allows you to attach a format to a Date field, before to drop the flow in your `Text output` step with unspecified field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know this would help or not but here is what I do to extract the date and use it in `Text File Output` step or even in `Table Input/Output` or `Execute SQL` step.

Do it in Job Level, split it into several transformation and use `Set variable` or `Copy row to result` step.

1st Transformation called `DateTime` transformation. In this transformation where you create dynamic datetime value that we will use later.

1. Use `Get System Info` step, make a field [Fieldname] with Type is : `system date (variable)`. [Fieldname] will contain current datetime when that transformation run.
2. Add `Calculator` Step, in here you do split the datetime [Fieldname] from `Get System Info` into several part.

Example (focus on this column)

Usually I split it into Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute

```
New Field  | Calculation                   | Field A     | Value type
-----------+-------------------------------+-------------+-----------
Daytrans   | Day of month of Date A        | [Fieldname] | String
Monthtrans | Month of Date A               | [Fieldname] | String
Yeartrans  | Year of Date A                | [Fieldname] | String
Hour       | Hour of Day of Date A         | [Fieldname] | String
Minute     | Minute of Hour of Date A      | [Fieldname] | String
Filename   | Set Field to Constant Value A | "Filename_" | String
```

Note. **"Filename_" with no quotation.**

3. Use `Formula` step to combine that date into whatever format you want.

Example. (yyyymmdd, yyyy/mm/dd)

```
New Field  | Formula                                                          | Value type
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
yyyymmdd   | [Filename] & [Yeartrans] & [Monthtrans] & [Daytrans]             | String
yyyy/mm/dd | [Filename] & [Yeartrans] & "/" & [Monthtrans] & "/" & [Daytrans] | String
```

Note. **You can creatively make your datetime format depend on your need**.

and make condition like this in `Formula` step:

`[Yeartrans] & if([Monthtrans] < 10; "0" & [Monthtrans]; [Monthtrans]) & if([Daytrans] < 10; "0" & [Daytrans]; [Daytrans])`.

I usually use it when i want the result is like this 20190701.
Why? Because if not using `if` function the result will like this 201971, without `0` on July 1st, 2019.

5. Use `Select Value` step to filter the field that you want to use, only this [yyyymmdd] and this [yyy/mm/dd] field.
6. Last is use `Set variable` or `Copy row to result` step, so you can use it in another transformation.

2nd Transformation called **Data Processing**

1. Use `Get Row from result` or `Get Variable` step and fill it with [fieldname] or variable that we made before.
2. Here is your data, whatever is it, from table, execute query, anything.
3. `Text File Output` step, where the configuration is in Filename box, you only need call the variable using this : `${Variablename}`

Done. And don't forget in `Text File Output`,`Fields` tab, fill it automatically using button Get Field or manually by your self.

You can also use that datetime variable in query, just check the `variable subtitution` box in `Execute Query` step or `Replace variable in script` box in `Table Input` step. Or output it as data in file by join 2 source using Join Row (Cartesian).

The Result will like this : `Filename_20190701.csv`

Sorry for my bad English, but hopefully this help.